# awk filter on numeric column but only when other string column equals some value

Tags: unix, awk

I want to exclude rows where col1 is "chr6" and col2 is between 25000000 and 33500000

have:

```
chr1 1000
chr6 24000000
chr6 26000000
chr6 27000000
chr6 40000000
chr7 100000
```

want:

```
chr1 1000
chr6 24000000
chr6 40000000
chr7 100000
```

I feel like it should be something the inverse of something like this, but not sure how to get there

```
awk '$1 = 'chr6 && $2 > 25000000 && $2 < 33500000'
```

Comment: It should be like: `awk '!($1 == "chr6" && $2 > 25000000 && $2 < 33500000)' Input_file` IMHO. You are using assignment operator, we have to use `==` to check condition. Moreover you have `'` in between `awk` program that's not allowed.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/G40WKR, `awk '!($1 == "chr6" && $2 > 25000000 && $2 < 33500000)'`

Comment: see: [inverse-regex-in-awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318846/inverse-regex-in-awk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to reverse 3 conditions and use `||` between them:

```sh
awk '$1 != "chr6" || $2 <= 25000000 || $2 >= 33500000' file

chr1 1000
chr6 24000000
chr6 40000000
chr7 100000
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use following `awk` program.

```
awk '!($1 == "chr6" && $2 > 25000000 && $2 < 33500000)' Input_file
```

OR:

```
awk '($1 == "chr6" && $2 > 25000000 && $2 < 33500000){next} 1' Input_file
```

***Fixes in OP's attempts:***

- You are using `=` assignment operator you should use `==` here to make it as a condition.
- Then you want to exclude matching results with condition so you need to use `!` operator here to avoid those results which actually match all conditions.
- Also `'` is not allowed in main program(in `'` form at least) of `awk`.
- To do comparison of string use `"` around string value(considering its not a variable).

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the other answers but I personally like to always put the value that should be in a range (`$2` in this case), in the middle of that range in the code for clarity so wanted to show how to write that:

```
awk '!( ($1=="chr6") && (25000000 < $2) && ($2 < 33500000) )' file
```

or if you wanted to write the negation of each part of that expression rather than negating the whole thing then move `$2` to outside of the range in the code:

```
awk '($1!="chr6") || ($2 <= 25000000) || (33500000 <= $2)' file
```